# Viewing Multiple images in Pickle file

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, pickle

I have a code in Python for viewing the images in a Pickle file .

The code I used :

```
train_images=pickle.load(open("full_CNN_train.p", "rb" ))
plt.imshow(train_images)
```

Here I got an error like this : **TypeError: Invalid shape (12764, 80, 160, 3) for image data**
So I added an addtional line to the code

```
plt.imshow(train_images[0])
```

Now I am able to get only **a single image output** where as the pickle file contains a large amount of images.

Pickle data format **print(train_images)**

[image]

How to view multiple images present in it ? Have I done anything wrong ? Please help me to solve this.Thank you !

Comment: It's a list of images. Something like "for image in train_images:
    plt.imshow(image)"

Comment: Yeah I applied that too but still I am able to view 1 image. Not able to view other images.Checked the size of train_images which is 12000 . Is there any other way ?

Comment: How would you like to see 12000 images? All at once? You could save the images as jpgs and use your favourite image viewer.

Comment: No I just want to take screenshots of 5 or 10 images to add them to my project report. I am using Spyder for running the code. Thank you mate! Can you just help me how to save the other images since I am able to see only 1 image

Comment: I have saved the current dataset image but I am not able to view the other images

Answer (score 0):

Try this to save some images

```
import pickle as pl
import cv2

fr = open('full_CNN_train.p', 'rb')
images = pl.load(fr)
fr.close()


for i in range(11):
    cv2.imwrite(f"img_{i * 1000}.jpg", images[i * 1000])
```